# SonarQube error in catch block in JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, java-11

I have below code. we are using sonar 8.9 version and jdk 11. SonarQube always throw an critical issue
"Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one"

```
try {
    String stringPayload = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
    log.info("Feedzai request: {}"<some object>);
    input.setPayload(new StringEntity(stringPayload, APPLICATION_JSON));
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}
```

I tried to replace catch "RuntimeException" from:

```
throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
```

to throw new

```
RuntimeException(String.format("RuntimeException during processing JSON %s", e.getMessage()),e);
```

But getting same error.
Could you please some one help me.

Comment: create a new class than extends `RuntimeException`

Comment: is there any other exception I can use instate of RuntimeException and resolve this issue?

Comment: what do you not try it and see?

Comment: Pass the original `e` to the exception constructor as _cause_. Two exceptions I like to use are `IllegalArgumentException` (related to passed data) and `IllegalStateException` (I am stuck here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of [RuntimeExteption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. **Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's `throws` clause** if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

You have two options:

1. Create a custom exception class
2. Throw already caught `JsonProcessingException`

Code for the first option will be:

```
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    //log message somewhere
    throw new MyCustomException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Code for the second option will be:

```
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    //log message somewhere
    throw;
}
```